# Android NumberFormat Currency

Tags: android, sqlite, currency

How can I convert the Currency to float? 
for example € 10,10 to 10.10

I tried it but no good.

```
float f = Float.valueOf(tv.getText().toString()).floatValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String temp = tv.getText().toString().replace.(",",".");
tv.setText(""+temp);

Comment: I did so but I get exception: `String temp = tv.getText().toString().replace(",",".");
 float f = Float.valueOf(temp);
 extras.putFloat("sale",f);`

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's no good, because you have to remove the character of the currency first (€, $...). You could use `String.replace("€", "")` for example, and then `Float.parseFloat(yourString)`.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, do not allow the user to type in any character but numbers so parsing does not fail

In the EditText for input

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType